# What is the physical meaning of Green's theorem and Green's identities?

Tags: diffraction, greens-functions

During the derivation of Kirchhoff and Fresnel Diffraction integral, many lectures and websites I found online pretty much follows the exact same steps from Goodman(Introduction to Fourier optics) in where diffraction starts with the [Green's theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuH2f.png) without any explanation how the equation was derived.
Some lectures online shows that this equation is came about by replacing the field [F with subtraction two first green's identities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqcTM.png). However, there is no explanation why this is done.

There are few websites that try to explain intuitions behind the Green's theorem (https://mathinsight.org/greens_theorem_idea), but I could not find any that explain the physical meaning of having F as two vector fields (G and U).

My initial understanding was that the Kirchhoff uses greens theorem because it resembles the physical phenomenon of Huygens principle. One would then assume that you would only have light field in the Green's theorem. There was a similar question on here [2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/371908/helmholtz-kirchhoff-integral-theorem) with similar question. My understanding from that page is G is the impulse function of the free space in which U travels through. And since G is the fundamental solution to the homogeneous Helmholtz equation, other forms of equations can be found by convolving with Green's function G.

In short, I would like to ask two question:

1. Is the following intuition correct?

Green's function as the fundamental solution to Helmholtz wave equation was not adequate in predicting diffraction Pattern. Therefore, Kirchhoff tried to find another solution by using the intuition of Huygens' Principle in Green's theorem where the vector field is the convolution of Light disturbance with the green's function(impulse function of free space).

2. Online lectures shows that F [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqcTM.png) is not the convolution of two vector fields and suggest that my understanding is wrong from the first question. How do you derive the Green's theorem [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuH2f.png)from Huygens Principle and why is the vector field F written like this [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqcTM.png)?